# ASP.NET MVC toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, widget, user-experience

I am coming from desktop dev background, wpf/SLight, and looking at switching to MVC application. Given I am absolutely rubbish at making stuff "pretty" what would be the best toolkit/widgets to invest in to help me on my way?

Looking for ease of use; UI look and feel; price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experience with following control toolkit.

**JQuery with JQuery UI** : http://jqueryui.com/ Free and open source. Lot of community support, Lot of plugin to extend. you have more control over plugins and code. Very light. I have extensively use several mvic projects and I do recommend.

**MVC controls toolkit**. : http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/ - Free and open source code plex projects that you can use your mvc application.

**DEvexprss mvc extension**.  http://mvc.devexpress.com/ :  Commercial product with all necessary control for mvc application. Learning curve is bit high. But you can get very nice look for your application easily. Customization is difficult. They have good support from you technical issues. I have use for projects.

**Kendo UI :** http://www.kendoui.com/  commercial product from Telerik. I haven’t use in commrical project this but seems good.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular UI frameworks is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (FREE). It is built on top of jQuery and has lots of pretty widgets that are easy to use.

Another framework I like to use is [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com/) from Telerik (Price depends on what you need). It is very declarative so you simply need to add attributes to your html elements and it will take care of styling for you.